# explanation of haproxy stats backend limit

Tags: haproxy

The relevant part of my `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` is:

```
global
    maxconn 30000
    ...

defaults
    ...

frontend frontend_for_all_sites
    maxconn 22000
    mode http
    bind *:80

    acl acl_hostname_www hdr_dom(host)    www.example.com
    acl acl_hostname_static hdr_dom(host) static.example.com
    use_backend www_backend      if acl_hostname_www
    use_backend static_backend   if acl_hostname_static

backend www_backend
    server www 127.0.0.1:9090 maxconn 500

backend static_backend
    server s 127.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 5000
```

So, I have 2 backends with only 1 backend each, without load balancing, but just proxying requests to different backends based on the request's hostname.

On the `www` backend I've set maxconn 500 and on the `static` backend I've set it to 5000.

The stats page now looks like this:

[image]

My question is what does the "Backend Limit" of 2200 for both backends represent? I understand that this value is 10% of the 22000 maxxconn on `frontend_for_all_sites`. Does this 2200 mean that the maximum amount of connections that the backends will process is 2200 and above that haproxy will return a 503?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is what does the "Backend Limit" of 2200 for both backends represent? I understand that this value is 10% of the 22000 maxxconn on frontend_for_all_sites.

`2200` in `Backend Limit` is the value of `fullconn` which is by default 10% of maxconn of frontend.

> Does this 2200 mean that the maximum amount of connections that the backends will process is 2200 and above that haproxy will return a 503?

No, the maximum amount of connections is sum of maxconn

Comment: I Had same question and just got the answer by this. thx for your explanation :)

Comment: So then it's not really a "Limit". Poor choice of words on the stats page.